# Not able to fetch data from Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I made a connection to the database using SQL studio and able to get results for query `Select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases;`
Now I am trying to get same data using C# but not getting anything.
I have used following code.

```
connectionString= "Data Source= gk2l4nmwrx.database.windows.net;Initial    Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=False;User ID=database_User_Id;Password=database_password;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" 
string cmdText = "select * from dbo.sysdatabases";
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data   Source="+connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    sqlCommand.CommandText = cmdText;
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", sqlReader["name"], sqlReader["status"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new SqlConnection("Data   Source="+connectionString)` ? What is the exception?

Comment: Your `connectionString` _already_ has `Data Source..` part. Why do you add it again?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the user id from:

`database_User_Id`

to:

`database_User_Id@gk2l4nmwrx`

username@servername

Also you're setting the `Data Source` **twice** from your code sample

Answer (score 0):

You should change your connection string Initial Catalog field. Replace

```
Initial    Catalog=database_name
```

by

```
Initial Catalog=master
```